# Unable to get Radio Button Check to work (PHP)

Tags: php, isset

I'm writing a small little webpage with 5 sickle cell anemia questions. I'm using the isset function to check the form elements and see if the user has selected a radio button for all 5 questions. But I cannot seem to make it work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['q1','q2','q3','q4','q5'])) {
        echo 'Your score is <font size="24" color="red">' . $score . '</font> out of 100';
    }    else { 
        echo "Please answer all questions";
    }

?>
```

Comment: I think you completely misunderstood how to use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) (-< Please read the manual!) `isset($_POST['q1','q2','q3','q4','q5'])` -> `isset($_POST["q1"], $_POST["q2"],...)`

Comment: I think he missunderstood the concept of arrays :D

Comment: You can only select one radio button. Maybe you mean checkboxes.

Comment: @earth2jason I edited my post clarify.

Comment: @Rizier123 I see now, I guess my question is then how can I check to see that all 5 questions have a radio button selected? Should I post the entire code here?

Comment: please up-vote also. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not writing isset in correct way:-

```
    if (isset($_POST["q1"],$_POST["q2"],$_POST["q3"],$_POST["q4"],$_POST["q5"])) {
        echo 'Your score is <font size="24" color="red">' . $score . '</font> out of 100';
    }    else { 
        echo "Please answer all questions";
    }

?>
```

If not understandable or you want to know exactly how's it working then read isset and array manual please.

Comment: You don't say. [Oh that's what we already know since over 15min](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450781/unable-to-get-radio-button-check-to-work-php#comment47067420_29450781)